# How to make a login system in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I made a login system connected to a database, but when I tried to redirect the user to home page, session seems to restart. I already know this can be established in php using cookies and sessions and I found lots of examples but I dont know how to do it in R.

User must be redirected to the home page while still being logged in. What happened was user logged out when I redirect them.

Here is a snippet of my code for server.R (already established db connection but it's not shown):

```
# Create a new table if it doesn't exist
  dbExecute(user_con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TINYTEXT , password_hash TEXT)")
  # Define a reactive value to store the user ID and username
  # Create a new table if it doesn't exist
  ## dbExecute(user_con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT UNIQUE, password_hash TEXT)")
  shinyjs::hide("logout_button1")
  shinyjs::hide("logout_button2")
  
  
  # Define a reactive value to store the user ID and username
  user_info <- reactiveValues(id = NULL, username = NULL)
  
  ## Hide the logout button initially
  user_logged_in <- reactive({
    !is.null(user_info$id)
  })
  ## shinyjs::hideElement("#logout_button")
  updateSession <- function(loggedIn) {
    user_info$loggedIn <- loggedIn
  }
  
 
  
  # Define an observer to handle login attempts
  observeEvent(input$login, {
    # Check if the input values are not empty, changed adding 
    if (input$username == "" || input$password == "") {
      # If either input value is empty, show an error message
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error",
          "Please enter your username and password",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
      
    } else {
      # Check if the credentials match a user in the database
      query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '%s'", input$username)
      result <- dbGetQuery(user_con, query)
      input_password <- charToRaw(input$password)
      
      
      if (nrow(result) == 1 && !is.na(result$password_hash) && digest(input_password, algo = "sha256") == result$password_hash) {
        # If the credentials are valid, store the user ID and username in the reactive values
        user_info$id <- result$id
        user_info$username <- input$username
        ##edited
        updateSession(TRUE)
        # Show a welcome message in a modal dialog
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Welcome",
            paste0("Welcome, ", user_info$username, "!"),
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
        shinyjs::show("logout_button1")
        shinyjs::show("logout_button2")
        hide("login_button")
        hide("register_button")
        shinyjs::runjs("setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = '/' }, 2000);")
      } else {
        # If the credentials are invalid, show an error message
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Error",
            "Invalid username or password.",
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
      }
      
      # Reset the login form
      updateTextInput(session, "username", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session, "password", value = "")
     
    }
  })
  
  # Define an observer to handle registration attempts
  observeEvent(input$register, {
    length_username <- nchar(input$new_username)
    length_password <- nchar(input$new_password)
    special_char <- input$new_password
    capital_letter <- input$new_password
    special_char_count <- nchar(gsub("[[:alnum:]\\s]", "", special_char))
    
    # Check if the input values are not empty
    if (input$new_username == "" || input$new_password == "" || input$confirm_password == "") {
      # If any input values are empty, show an error message
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error",
          "Please enter a username and password, and confirm your password.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
      
    }
    
    ##Adding password and username being 8 characters long
    
    else if (length_username <8 || length_password < 8) {
      # If any input values are less than 8 characters show error message
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error",
          "Please enter a username and password that are at least 8 characters long",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
      
    }
    
    ##Adding passwords having special characters (at least 2)
    
    else if (special_char_count < 2) {
      
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error",
          "Please enter a password that has at least 2 special character.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
      
    } 
    
    else if(!grepl("[A-Z]", capital_letter)){
      
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error",
          "Please enter a password that has at least 1 capital letter.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
      
    }
    
    
    
    else {
      # Check if the new username is available
      query <- sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '%s'", input$new_username)
      result <- dbGetQuery(user_con, query)
      
      if (result[[1]] != 0) {
        # If the new username is already taken, show an error message
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Error",
            "Username is already taken.",
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
        
      } else if (input$new_password != input$confirm_password) {
        # If the passwords do not match, show an error message
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Error",
            "Passwords do not match.",
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
        
      } else {
        # If the new username is available and passwords match, add the user to the database
        password_hash <- digest(input$new_password, algo = "sha256")
        query <- sprintf("INSERT INTO users (username, password_hash) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", input$new_username, password_hash)
        dbExecute(user_con, query)
        
        # Log in the user automatically after registration
        user_info$id <- dbGetQuery(user_con, paste0("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '", input$new_username, "'"))$id
        user_info$username <- input$new_username
        
        updateSession(TRUE)
        # Show a welcome message in a modal dialog
        
        
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Welcome",
            paste0("Welcome, ", user_info$username, "!"),
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
        
       
        ## hide("login_button")
        ## hide("register_button")
        shinyjs::hide("register_button")
        
        shinyjs::hide("login_button")
        shinyjs::show("logout_button1")
        shinyjs::show("logout_button2")
        # Reset the registration form
        updateTextInput(session, "new_username", value = "")
        updateTextInput(session, "new_password", value = "")
        updateTextInput(session, "confirm_password", value = "")
        shinyjs::runjs("setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = '/' }, 2000);")
      }
    }
  })
  
  # Define an observer to handlelogout attempts
  observeEvent(input$logout, {
    ##Loggedout, cookie false
    
    # Clear the user info from the reactive values
    user_infoid <- NULL
    user_info$username <- NULL
    
    
    updateSession(FALSE)
    ##adding message
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "Thank you and come back!",
        paste0("Thank you", user_info$username, "!"),
        easyClose = TRUE
      )
    )
    # Show login and registration buttons
    
    ##shinyjs::showElement("#login_buttons")
    shinyjs::show("register_button")
    
    shinyjs::show("login_button")
    ##shinyjs::hideElement("#logout_button")
    shinyjs::hide("logout_button1")
    shinyjs::hide("logout_button2")
    # Reset the login and registration forms
    updateTextInput(session, "username", value = "")
    updateTextInput(session, "password", value = "")
    updateTextInput(session, "new_username", value = "")
    updateTextInput(session, "new_password", value = "")
    updateTextInput(session, "confirm_password", value = "")
   
    shinyjs::runjs("setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = '/' }, 2000);") 
  })
  
 
  
  ## Define an observer to show/hide UI elements depending on whether the user is logged in
  observe({
    if (user_logged_in()) {
      
      
      
      
      # Hide the login and registration buttons, show the logout button
      ##shinyjs::hideElement("#login_buttons")
      hide("login_button")
      hide("register_button")
      ##shinyjs::showElement("#logout_button")
      show("logout_button1")
      show("logout_button2")
     
      ##REDIRECT TO HOME PAGE
     shinyjs::runjs("setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = '/' }, 2000);")
     
      
      
    } else {
     
      # Show the login and registration buttons, hide the logout button
      ##shinyjs::showElement("#login_buttons")
      show("login_button")
      show("register_button")
      ## shinyjs::hideElement("#logout_button")
      hide("logout_button2")
      hide("logout_button2")
      
    }
  })
  

  ## Disconnect from the user database when the app is closed
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    dbDisconnect(user_con)
  })  ##end of login and register codes
  
}##end function
```

<sub>I know that my code isn't super clean as I was debugging it to see what's the issue.</sub>

Comment: I applaud the exercise, but reinventing authentication systems is perhaps not wise. My first suggestion is to ***NEVER*** paste in a username into your query, it is a clear example where [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables") can occur. If you're going to continue down this road, you must fix this, best with [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the reply! will do, thing is this is my first time using R and not sure if php or web normal statements in js even work here to a certain degree, and i really didnt want to reinvent an authentication system from scratch but R didnt have any authentication system that has external database that i could use.....if you have any or know anything about this please let me know!

Comment: Look into `shinyauthr` and (somewhere?) `shinyauth` for starters. How you intend to serve it is also important, are you planning to host in the free `shiny-server`, or through some online server (shinyapps.io), or via Posit Connect (commercial shiny-server, lots lots lots of goodness here, though not cheap)?

Comment: FYI, be very careful about "rolling your own" authentication. Time and again it has been shown that even those fairly proficient in a language over-estimate their understanding of authentication considerations and security. Your SQL injection here should be a warning klaxon here, and I mean that not to insult you, more to help you realize that you don't yet know what you don't know about authentication systems. Auth is complicated and rife with so many holes and issues that "we" have learned from our costly mistakes. Be humble, realize you don't know what you don't know here.

Comment: Now I'm not saying that `shinyauthr` or whatever are awesome at this, I have not audited it completely, so it's entirely possible that they're making similar mistakes. But since you're starting from scratch and those packages/libraries have gone through some iterations, perhaps they've already worked through more of the potential issues.

Comment: @r2evans yeah i understand, i will modify it accordingly, as for shinyautr package this is what i found but as you can see the dataframe holds info that only enables users i chose before, not like registering new users etc, idk how to change the code to fit it as a random user regisering and giving me their info not me deciding them as the code shows:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyauthr/readme/README.html